# searching in belongsToMany relationship in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

Actually i want to search those question which user want to search after select any subject or course.

if a remove either `whereHas` from subject or course its works but with both its not working.

Please give a better solution for searching in belongsToMany realtionship.

i have a question table with `Question` model class

```
class Question extends Model{
    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Course','course_questions');
    }

    public function subjects(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Subject','subject_questions');
    }
}
```

and in my `searchController`

```
public function index(Request $request){
        $questions = Question::with(['user','courses','branches','subjects','years','universities','question_type'])
            ->where("status","=",1)
            ->where(function($query) use($request){
                $q = $request->q;
                if(isset($q) && !is_null($q)){
                    $query->where("question","LIKE","%$q%");
                }
            })
            ->whereHas('subjects',function($query) use($request){
                $subjects = $request->subject;
                if(isset($subjects)){
                    $_subjects = explode(" ",$subjects);
                    $query->whereIn("slug",$_subjects)
                    ->orWhereIn("subject_name",$_subjects);
                }
            })
            ->whereHas('courses',function($query) use($request){
                $course = $request->course;
                if(isset($course)){
                    $_course = explode(" ",$course);
                    $query->whereIn("slug",$_course)
                        ->orWhereIn("course",$_course);
                }
            })
            ->paginate();
        if($request->ajax()){
            $returnHTML = view('questions.question_list')->with('questions', $questions)->render();
            return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'pageContent'=>$returnHTML));
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should build your query probably this way - you should verify conditions before adding any constraints to your query:

```
$query = Question::with(['user','courses','branches','subjects','years','universities','question_type'])
            ->where("status","=",1);

$q = $request->q;
if(isset($q) && !is_null($q)) {
    $query = $query->where("question","LIKE","%$q%");
}

$subjects = $request->subject;
if (isset($subjects)) {
    $query = $query->whereHas('subjects',function($query) use($subjects){                
        $_subjects = explode(" ",$subjects);
        $query->whereIn("slug",$_subjects)
       ->orWhereIn("subject_name",$_subjects);                
   });
}

$course = $request->course;
if (isset($course)) {
    $query = $query->whereHas('courses',function($query) use($course ){       
        $_course = explode(" ",$course);
        $query->whereIn("slug",$_course)
       ->orWhereIn("course",$_course);
    });
}

$questions = $query->paginate();
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I spent lotsof time on it but now It's magically works. . But how its working, Please explain.

Comment: @Jeetendra There's no much to explain. You need to add conditions to your query only when you have some filters set. In code you added some conditions using `whereHas` you've always add those even in case no filters were filled by user and it caused result you don't expect

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Product::query()->
    WhereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
        $q->where('products.name', $keyword)
            ->orWhere('categories.name', $keyword);
    })->get();
```

> This is how I have used in my project